# Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0. CCnet

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config, cruisecontrol.net

Hello I got this error when I am trying to access my published website online.
I searched and did what is ask on everything like the removal of single quotes and proper syntax of connection string in the webconfig but I still got this error.

My solution is working fine on my local pc but when it is uploaded thru CC.Net the error is encountered please help I dont know if it has something to do with ccnet changing the constrings or what.

Comment: Its is too broad for SO. Please add more details.

Comment: nvm got this working if ever any one encountered this error try doing this.
[MeLoveyouRuntime](http://www.meloveyouruntime.com/2012/09/25/replaceable-token-issue-with-config-connectionstring-transforms/)